How to escape pipe char | to pass it to cypress environnement by command line parameter?
I would like to be able to pass the string "my pass|word" cypress environment by command line.
Here is the command :
npx cypress run --spec .\cypress\e2e\tests\temp.cy.ts --env JIRA_PASS="my pass|word"

How to escape this pipe char?
When i access my env variable with Cypress.env().JIRA_PASS, the pipe char is changed into a comma.
I've tried different ways to escape with , ^, ', ` but none of them seems to work.
It seems like the same problem occur to when you add a , into the env variable.
Any solution?
(I need to do this to pass a creds from jenkins to a cypress script running on docker from a jenkins pipeline).
I tryed to search doc, differents method to escape, but none of them work.

I found out the solution :
By using sytem environnement variable, we can set some cypress env variable.
That's a good news, because system env variables dont complain about having char like , or |
So we do export CYPRESS_JIRA_PASS=my pass|word and then follow up with npx cypress run --spec .\cypress\e2e\tests\temp.cy.ts and when accessing the variable with Cypress.env().JIRA_PASS, the value will be correct and unchanged.

Since you are passing credentials, use Option #2: cypress.env.json.
Save remembering entering passwords on the command line, and can be excluded from repository via .gitignore.
{
  "JIRA_PASS": "my pass|word"
}

it('confirms the password special chars', () => {
  expect(Cypress.env('JIRA_PASS')).to.eq('my pass|word')
})


If you already use cypress.env.json and want to check it in to Github, use password.env.json to store the sensitive data.
Read it into cypress.config.js like this:
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const password = require('./password.env.json');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  env: {
    //  hard-coded env values here
    ...password
  },
})


My guess is that something with how Cypress parses environment variables via the --env flag is causing the | character to be replaced. It is probably worth posting in the Cypress github with an issue to see if they have a reason for the replacement, or maybe it's just a bug.
If you were certain you'd only have that one comma in the password, you could just use String.replace to alter the password back to the original value.
Cypress.env('JIRA_PASS', Cypress.env('JIRA_PASS').replace(',', '|'));

Through my testing, I found that consuming a variable via an environment variable prefixed with CYPRESS_ will not cause the replacement to occur. If possible, I'd recommend this strategy.
CYPRESS_JIRA_PASS="my pass|word" npx cypress run

